# expl3 get expresion evaluation afterward

Tags: expl3

I'm working on a latex exam class using expl3 language.
Each section is representing an exercise with several questions in it.
An exercise is defined with a given number of point.

From this structure, I want to automatically, display the total number of point for the given exercise.

For instance, the result would be :

[image: structure example]

I want to provide a latex interface like this one :

```latex
\excercise

\question{2}
...

\question{2}
...
```

In order to implement this interface, I need to find out a way to perform an expression evaluation postponed to the very last moment of the compilation process. This solution would enable us to get all question value defined later in the source code.

The following source code is my attempt to implement this idea.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_points_per_question_seq % Store the point of each section
\int_zero_new:N \g_current_sec_int % Counter of the current exercise




\DeclareDocumentCommand{\addpoint} {m} % Add the arg to the current exercise total point 
{
    \pt_add_point:Nn \g_points_per_question_seq {#1} 
}

  
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pt_add_point:Nn #1 #2 { %  intern method
    \group_begin:
        \tl_set_eq:NN \l_foo_tl \c_empty_tl %  create a temp token variable

        \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_points_per_question_seq \l_foo_tl  % get the current exercise total point
        
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpk_fp  {\tl_head:N \l_foo_tl  } % Create a local float variable for addition purpose
        \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpk_fp  { #2 } % Add the argument value to the local variable
        
        \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_points_per_question_seq { \fp_to_tl:N \l_tmpk_fp } % Push back the new total point of the current exercise
    \group_end:
}



\DeclareDocumentCommand{\flush} {} % Declare a new exercise 
{
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_points_per_question_seq {0.0} % Set the total point of the new exercise
    \int_gadd:Nn \g_current_sec_int 1 % Incr the exercise number
}


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\displaytotalpoint} {} % Display the total point of the current exercise.
{
     \seq_item:Nn  \g_points_per_question_seq  {\int_use:N \g_current_sec_int}  % Get the associeted seq element 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\exercise}{
\flush
\section{Exercise : \displaytotalpoint~points}
}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
\addpoint{#1}
\subsection{Question : #1 points}
}



\begin{document}

\maketitle


\exercise

\question{2.0}
.....
\question{2.0}
.....
```

The result is the following one :

[image: bad result]

As you can see, the total point is not good since it has to be equals to 4. However, when I plot the sequence state at the end, it successfully contains the number 4 at the first index.

So I guess that I need to postpone the seq_item instruction after the evaluation of all questions that belongs to the current exercise.

How can I avoid as long as possible the expression expand of this statement in order to get what I want?

```
 \seq_item:Nn  \g_points_per_question_seq  {\int_use:N \g_current_sec_int}
```

Have you an idea of how to implement this structure?

Huge thank's to those who will read and answer me!

Comment: I think a two-run solution would be the right thing to do. Write the sequence at the end of the LaTeX run (inside the `\AtEndDocument` hook) into a file which you read in at the start of your LaTeX run if it is available and use the points contained in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of things are normally done by writing to the aux-file. A simple variant would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Exercise \ref{ex:points}pt

Questions 

Questions 
\makeatletter 
\def\@currentlabel{4}% or for example your `int` variable. 
\label{ex:points}%label  
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

More sophisticated variants are possible, e.g. with the zref-package, but the principle stays the same.